# Can't properly keep track of connected clients java

Tags: java, multithreading, server

I can't seem to figure out how to notify my Server class that a connection was lost. My server code is:

```
public class Server {

    static int port = 4444;
    static boolean listening = true;
    static ArrayList<Thread>Clients = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    static MatchMaker arena;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Initialize();
        Thread startConnections = new Thread(run());
        startConnections.start();
    }

    private static Runnable run(){
        System.out.println("(" +  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()) + ") Started listening on port: " + port);
        try(ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port)){
            while(listening){
                if(Clients.size() <= 4){
                    Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();

                    MultiThread connection = new MultiThread(clientSocket, arena, );
                    Clients.add(connection);

                    System.out.println("Client connected from " + clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " Assigned ID: " + connection.getId());
                    System.out.println("Currently connected clients(" + Clients.size() + "): ");
                    for(int i = 0; i < Clients.size(); i++)
                        System.out.println("   - " + Clients.get(i).getId());
                    connection.start();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static void Initialize(){
        arena = new MatchMaker();
    }

}
```

The problem here is that since this class keeps track of the connected clients I want it to notice when a client has lost connection. The MultiThread class already has a functional way of detecting clients that lost connection, however I don't know how to pass that information back to the Server class. I've tried passing the server class to MultiThread as a parameter, but it said I couldn't use 'this' in a static manner.

Comment: Btw, in `main` your code isn't starting a new thread at all and is broken. You could just call `run()` instead of this code.

Comment: And there's no code in `Server` which is supposed to handle notifications about a disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep them in synchronized map like:

```
Map<Integer, ClientObject> connectedClients = new HashMap<Integer, ClientObject>(); //key integer will be the client id
```

Other suggestion:

```
Map<String, ClientObject> connectedClients = new HashMap<String, ClientObject>(); //key String will be the client IP&userName (you decide)
```

Comment: How am I supposed to access the Map in the other class?

Comment: you can create a singleton which helps you insert/get data from this. the singleton will actually manage all the connected clients you got

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all use thread safe collection for monitoring the client connection so replace the following
    ArrayList Clients = new ArrayList();
with 
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue Clients = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
But your problem is that you are trying to use limited resource in thread safe manner so best option would be using Semaphore. I have re factored your class a bit to give an idea.Hope it helps. Plz look closely on 'SERVER_INSTANCE'.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Server {
    private final int MAX_AVAILABLE = 4;
    public final Semaphore SERVER_INSTANCE = new Semaphore(MAX_AVAILABLE, true);

    static int port = 4444;
    static volatile boolean listening = true;
    static MatchMaker arena;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Initialize();
        Thread startConnections = new Thread(run());
        startConnections.start();
    }

    private static void Initialize() {
        //do somthing
    }

    private static Runnable run(){
        System.out.println("(" +  new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()) + ") Started listening on port: " + port);
        ServerSocket socket = null;
        while(listening){
           try {
                socket = new ServerSocket(port);
               try {
                   SERVER_INSTANCE.acquire();
                       Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();
                       MultiThread connection = new MultiThread(clientSocket, arena, SERVER_INSTANCE);

               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();          
               }
           } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    static class MultiThread implements Runnable{
        Semaphore serverInstance ;
        public MultiThread(Socket clientSocket, MatchMaker arena, Semaphore serverInstance) {
            serverInstance = serverInstance;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverInstance.acquire();
                //Do your work here
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                serverInstance.release();
            }
        }
    }

        class MatchMaker {

        }
}
```